# Why isn't my delete node function actually deleting the node?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list that is more like a C linked list, but it's not removing the node permanently. When I print out the linked list after I run the function, the node is still there. Why isn't my delete node function actually deleting the node?

```
bool removeFromList(int delID, node* &head){

    node* temp = new node;
    node* curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL && curr->id != delID){
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(curr == NULL){
        cout << delID << " was not in the has table." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        node* next = curr->next;
        cout << "Node with id " << curr->id << " was deleted." << endl;
        delete curr;
        curr = NULL;
        temp->next = next;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you initialize temp with a `new node`? Later you are assigning a value to temp and you're losing the memory assigned to temp.

Comment: ^^^ Short version: Deleting a node should require *no* new allocations. Related, to do this right, walking a pointer-to-pointer, starting with its value from `&head` (which will work because `head is a reference to the real pointer) down to the node to delete, makes this task **much** cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

When the element to remove is the first of the list, you should assign head to the second (if exists) element of the list. That is:

```
bool removeFromList(int delID, node* &head){
    //Checking for the front of the list
    if (head != NULL && head->id == delID){
         head = head->next;
         return true;
    }

    node* temp; //You don't need to initialize this
    ...//the rest of your code may remains equal
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign head to the second element in the list